# $f$ holomorphic and bounded on $\mathbb{C}-K$, $K=\{0\}\cup\{\frac1n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f$ be holomorphic and bounded on $\mathbb{C}-K$, $K=\{0\}\cup\{\frac1n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, with $f(2)=1$. Find all possibilities for the function $f$.

I am in doubt how to solve this exercise. It seems that all singularities, except for the one at $0$, is removable, since the given function in bounded outside $K$, continuing this logic, $f$ thus extends to an analytic, bounded function on $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$; again continuing this logic we see that the function extends to an analytic, bounded, entire function, thus $f\equiv1$ on $\mathbb{C}$. Is this correct? If not, any hints how to proceed?

Comment: Yes, your argument is correct.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy, thank you for your comment!